# angular drop event is inconsistent

Tags: angular, angular9

> Minimal reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/buggydrop

I'm making a simple website when user drag an element and drop it on another element so that the content of each element swap with each other.

However, the problem is in `(drop)="BuggyonDrop($event)"` the `$event` is giving the `DragEvent` on dragged element.

In other words, if I drag `<p id="unique0">` and drop it on `<p id="unique2">` the event info on `drop()` is `<p id="unique0">`...

The weird part is, when I do `console.log(event.target.id)` the result is `unique2`.

Additionally, if I put debugger right below the `console.log` the result is fine (working as intended).

So it's really weird and inconsistent.

I had to spend hours and hours to find the cause and workaround. turns out not using `*ngFor` was a solution (have to put data-binded-value manually one by one).

I've tested on chrome and opera...

[here is the console.log result when I do the following code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdiCz.jpg)

```
console.log("BuggyonDrop")
console.log(event)
console.log(event.target)
console.log(event.target.id)
```

as you can see, `event.target` is giving `unique3` element but when I do `event.target.id` it's giving me `unique0`

Not really sure why is it behaving in such way

Comment: Your example seems good to me, I've stripped some console.log ... try dragging "buggy0"  to "buggy4" and check the console then do the same thing with "not_buggy0" and drag it on "not_buggy4" ... it gives the same result: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-60662981

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the `ngFor` loop tracks the items by value. In your code, you swap the value of the two items involved in the drag/drop operation. The loop probably swaps the item indexes in the loop to keep the same value at the same position.

To ensure that the `ngFor` loop index refers to the correct target element, you should [track](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#ngForTrackBy) the items by index:

```
*ngFor="let id of good.idArray; index as i; trackBy: trackByIndex"
```

where `trackByIndex` is a method of the component class:

```
public trackByIndex(index, item) {
  return index;
}
```

See [this modified version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nxdzgo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) of your stackblitz for a demo. You will notice that I renamed a few properties to reflect the fact that the drag and drop is not buggy anymore...

Comment: thanks for the reply, while this work very well I still would like to know why is it behaving this way I mean, my code still change the context of the node upon being swapped

Comment: I added an explanation to the answer.